# Processing static htm using spawn function

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, pipe, spawn

I try to write web server for debuging purpose.
Before sending a response it processes static html files with gpp (general purpose preprocessor).

```
    var app = http.createServer(function(req, res){

    if( req.url.match( /\.html$/ )){

        send( req, '.' + req.url ).pipe( res, [ gpp.stream() ]);
    }
    else{

        send(req, '.' + req.url).pipe( res );
    }

}).listen(8000);
```

I use "send" npm package patched by me. Originally "send" send static files supporting them with HTTP headers.
I added array of streams to original module to transform requested static files.

```
   // pipe
  var stream = fs.createReadStream(path, options);
  this.emit('stream', stream);

  var sm = stream;

  if (transforms instanceof Array) {
      for (var i=0; i<transforms.length; i++) {
          sm = sm.pipe(transforms[i]);
      }
  }

  sm.pipe(res);
```

gpp module:

```
module.exports.stream = function(){

var gpp = spawn( 'gpp', [ '-Iapp' ]);

gpp.stdin.pipe = function( dest, pipeOpts ){

    return Readable.prototype.pipe.apply( gpp.stdout, arguments );
}

return gpp.stdin;
};
```

**Problem is that: html page isn't loaded into browser completely.**

My html page source (i omited needless staff):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<head>
#include "scripts-debug.tpl.html"
</head>
<body>
#include "body.tpl.html"
</body>
</html>
```

What i see in browser (view page source):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<head>
<!-- scripts-debug.tpl.html -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/con
```

If i change in gpp module

```
var gpp = spawn( 'gpp', [ '-Iapp' ]);
```

to

```
var gpp = spawn( 'grep', [ '.' ]);
```

it works fine ( page is loaded as is )

If i change in send module

```
sm.pipe(res);
```

to

```
sm.pipe( fs.createWriteStream( 'test.dst' ));
```

it works fine ( processed page is loaded into a file )

If i do:

```
cat app/index-debug.html | gpp -Iapp
```

it works fine ( processed page is on stdout )

I suppose that there is a problem somewhere in streams synchronization.
But i can't find it.

Comment: I found what cause the problem. This is due to Content-Length of response that set as size of original file, not transformed one. I'll describe a fix as soon as i do it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is impossible to wrap gpp with stream.

Comment: I must set Content-Length before any chunk of data will be sent. My solution was to include gpp call into send module.